# How can I produce an alert if three out of nine checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have nine checkboxes linked to nine images and three of them use the name 'correct' using the code shown below.

```
<div class="nine">
            <label for="correct1"><img class="picture1" src="picture1.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="correct1" name="correct"/>
            </div>
```

The remaining six are unnamed using the code shown below.

```
<div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4"/>
            </div>
```

I currently have the following code to produce an alert if the three checkboxes with the name "correct" are checked but it isn't working.

```
<script>
var i, correct = document.getElementsByName('correct');
            for (i = 0; i <= correct.length; i++) {
                if (correct[i].checked) {
                    alert('correct');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            alert('incorrect');
            return false;
            </script>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Currently your code is not in a function, so `return false;` doesn't do anything. You're likely running this before the checkboxes are loaded into memory. You need to wrap your code in `window.onload = function () { ... };` or put it in an event handler.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me how to do this?

Comment: It would be better for everyone if you could try and do this yourself. I'm of the opinion that giving people already-written code does not help people learn how to code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean though because I'm only learning

Comment: @ThreeLegs Wouldn't be easy to use a selector like: `$("#correct1:checked").length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6:

```js
const correctInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="correct"]')];

const alertIfThree = () => {
  const checkedCorrectInputs = correctInputs.filter(input => input.checked);
  if (checkedCorrectInputs.length > 2) {
    alert('Alert');
  }
};

correctInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', alertIfThree));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
```

- `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="correct"]')` gets all inputs with name "correct".
- `[...CODE]` is [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), it converts code from previous point to array.
- `correctInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', alertIfThree))` adds click event listener to each of them. That event listener is function `alertIfThree()`.
- `alertIfThree()` filters out those input elements that are not checked and produces alert if there are more than 2 of them.

#### EDIT

In response to your comment:

```js
// jshint esnext: true

const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="correct"], input[name="incorrect"]')];

const alertIfCorrect = () => {
  const checkedInputs            = inputs.filter(input => input.checked),
        noIncorrectCheckedInputs = checkedInputs.find(input => input.name === 'incorrect') === undefined;
  if (checkedInputs.length > 2 && noIncorrectCheckedInputs) {
    alert('Alert');
  }
};

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', alertIfCorrect));
```

```html
<p>Correct:
  <input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
</p>
<p>Incorrect:
  <input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
</p>
```

- `const` is [ES6 constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). *"The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared"*.
- `[...CODE_HERE]` is so called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Here, it turns what it contains after ellipsis into an array. Other way to do it would be to use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- `() => {` and `input => CODE_HERE` are [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are ES6's syntactic sugar for function declaration.
  What stands before `=>` are parameters. `()` stands for 0 parameters. If you wanted function that takes few parameters, those braces would need to have those few parameters inside them. For one parameter, parameter's name can replace braces altogether (like in second code in this bullet point).
  What stands after `=>` is either expression or group of statements. Statements are surrounded by curly brackets (`{}`). If you omit them, you are writing an expression that your function will return. For example `input => input.checked` is equivalent to `function(input) { return input.checked; }`.
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) are methods of array prototype. They respectively filter and search an array using condition defined in a function that is passed to them as a parameter. Read more by following those two links.

If you need something else explained, let me know. Those functions and structures here are pretty... fresh, so you can just not know them yet.

Comment: I've just tried your example now and it works and produces an alert when the three "correct" checkboxes are checked. However, it also produces an alert when the three "correct" checkboxes are checked and the "incorrect" checkboxes are checked too. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @ThreeLegs: See the new code below "Edit", under "Show code snippet".

Comment: That works a charm, thank you! Would it be possible for you to add comments to the code so I can understand how it works? I'm new to all of this and still learning

Comment: @ThreeLegs: Done. I'm glad you want to understand it and not just copy-paste it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the code to link to another webpage? Like "example.html"?

Comment: @ThreeLegs: You must clarify your question. If you want to redirect user to another webpage, the code for that is: `window.location.href = 'http://example.com/'`.

Comment: I want to change the code so that it redirects the user to another webpage in the same folder stored on my server. For example, the webpage which I implemented this solution on is example1.html and I want it to redirect to example2.html when the three checkboxes are checked. Is this possible?

Comment: @ThreeLegs: Replace `alert('Alert')` with `window.location.href = 'example2.html'`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over all of the checkboxes, checking their state. Once this is done, create a variable "correct" and initialize it to true.  Then go to each state in the variable and, if you find that its name isn't "correct" and it is checked or its name is "correct" and it isn't correct, set the variable to false. Then check if the variable is true and, if it is, display the alert.

View an example here: https://repl.it/GxsE/9

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Would it be possible for you to show me how to do this? I'm new to coding and don't know how to implement this myself

Comment: @ThreeLegs I've added an example into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in a JSfiddle and it works for me. I just wrapped your JS in a function and added an onclick event.

```
  <div class="nine">
            <label for="correct1"><img class="picture1" src="picture1.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="correct1" name="correct"onclick="validate()"/>
</div>


<div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4" onclick="validate()"/>
 </div>


    <script type=text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
    var i, correct = document.getElementsByName('correct');
                for (i = 0; i <= correct.length; i++) {
                    if (correct[i].checked) {
                        alert('correct');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                alert('incorrect');
                return false;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: This can not possibly work because the logic is wrong, it alerts correct upon checking the very first of the elements that has the name of 'correct'  it disregards all the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check the loop. Use `for (i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {` instead `for (i = 0; i <= correct.length; i++) {`

```js
var i, correct = document.getElementsByName('correct');
var correct_answers = [];
function validate(){
    correct_answers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
        var element = correct[i].getAttribute("id");
        var checked = correct[i].checked;
        correct_answers.push({element,checked});
    }
}

function show(){
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML ="";
  for(var e=0;e<correct_answers.length;e++){
    var box = document.createElement('div');
box.innerHTML = correct_answers[e].element+ " " + correct_answers[e].checked+ "<br>";

    document.getElementById('results').appendChild(box);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="nine">
            <label for="correct1"><img class="picture1" src="picture1.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="correct1" name="correct"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="correct2"><img class="picture1" src="picture1.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="correct2" name="correct"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="correct3"><img class="picture1" src="picture1.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="correct3" name="correct"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="incorrect4"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="incorrect5"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="incorrect6"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="incorrect7"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nine">
            <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="picture4.jpg"/></label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" class="chk" id="incorrect8"/>
            </div>
            
            <button onclick="show();">show results</button>
            <div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't work, it gives an alert after the first checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

It will require some javascript. You will need o check the checkboxes each time one changes. So to start with you will need to check your checkboxes, assuming they have an assigned class of 'chk'. This can be done with a querySelector.

Each time a checkbox changes, the function 'check_checkboxes()' is called. This function will see for each checkbox with `name='correct'` if it is checked and then increment 'count'

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".chk");

var correct = document.querySelectorAll("[name=correct]");

function check_checkbox() {
  var count = 0;
  [].forEach.call(correct, function(item) {
    if (item.checked) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  

  if (count >= 3) {
    alert("count of 3 or more");
  }
}

[].forEach.call(checkboxes, function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("change", function() {
    check_checkbox();
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="nine">
  <label for="correct1"><img class="picture1" src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="correct1" name="correct" />
</div>

<div class="nine">
  <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4" />
</div>
<div class="nine">
  <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4" name="correct" />
</div>
<div class="nine">
  <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4" />
</div>
<div class="nine">
  <label for="incorrect1"><img class="picture4" src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="incorrect4" name="correct" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use document.querySelectorAll('input[name]=correct') in your code.

Comment: in this case, "correct" is the value of the name attribute, rather than a class name so this won't work.

Comment: Even after the edit it won't work, because that is not valid syntax. You've also not shown how to use the code you're showing to find the values the user needs. Please read [answer] for tips on how to write a good answer.

Comment: If user get these values then he can loop through the code. No need to post whole code here.